draw texturing take account of face's orientation?
When i texture an object by drawing onto a mesh (mix mode, strength = 1), i can't paint faces that are not perpendicular to the camera.


(But it works if i paint directly on the image texture)
so come questions :
How to disable this ?
The more the orientation is far from perpendicular to the camera, the lighter the color is ?
(The normals are all flipped outside)

The angle setting is in Falloff:

You can disable this by pressing Normal Falloff.
Disabling Backface culling in Options allows painting on flipped faces:

Disabling Occlude allows painting trough faces.
